# Memory Error in Python - how to use less memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import string
from itertools import product

l = string.ascii_letters+string.digits+'-'+'_'    
def combinations(a,times):
    comb = list(product(a, repeat=times))
    i = 0
    a = []
    while(i < len(comb)):
        s = ''.join(comb[i])
        a.append(s)
        i+=1
    return a
a = combinations(l,4)
print(a)
```

I have a random hashed string that can be up to ten characters and I want to check every string possibility, hash it and compare the hashes until I get the string. But when i want to have all the possibilities of a string of 4 characters it gives me a Memory error. I want to go up to 10 characters.

This is the error that I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "source_file.py", line 14, in <module>
    a = combinations(l,4)
File "source_file.py", line 6, in combinations
    comb = list(product(a, repeat=times))
MemoryError
```

Comment: Have you done the math to realize how many possible combinations you're trying to create? 64 characters times 64 characters times 64 characters times 64 characters yields 16,777,216 different strings. That's just with four. With five it becomes 1,073,741,824 different strings. Each string takes up five bytes (plus perhaps a tiny bit more for overhead). That's 5,368,709,120 bytes to hold the strings for combinations of 5 characters.

Comment: @BryanOakley how can I fix it?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "fix". If you write them to disk one and then throw them away from memory, you just need lots of disk space. If you want to keep them all in memory at the same time, you need lots of system memory. If you don't need to keep any of them (just print them out one at a time, for example),  you can print them one at a time or use a generator.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have a random string that is hashed and I want to check every possibility, hash it and compare the hashes until I get the string

Comment: If you're doing that by generating every possible string, be prepared to wait years for your answer. If that's your real goal, modify your question to explain what you're doing so that someone can tell you how to solve _that_ problem, rather than the problem of generating billions upon billions of random strings.

Comment: Assuming it takes a ns (which is a very generous assumption) to hash and compare, you might not even see the answer in your life. It would take 36 years.

Comment: @BryanOakley "tiny bit more for overhead"? You must have a strange definition of "tiny".

Comment: Have you thought about buying a quantum computer?

Comment: @Olivier Hahahah, a HPC could do it btw! I mean a group of them!

Comment: @StefanPochmann: You are correct. I was too lazy to look up how much extra python adds to the storage of a string. I was thinking it was just a couple bytes, but it's way more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Like this...

To save memory, you want to use a generator so the whole list is not stored in memory.

```
def combinations(a,times):
    for combination in product(a, repeat=times):
        yield ''.join(combination)
```

You can then use it like this.

```
l = string.ascii_letters+string.digits+'-'+'_' 
combination_generator = combinations(l, 4)

# This will work, but takes a few minutes
for c in combination_generator:
    print(c)
```

#### But...

You are no longer out of memory, now you will be out of time. There are 64^10 combinations for a ten characters string. That is 1,152,921,504,606,846,976. You will most likely never reach the end of that generator in your life.

Comment: That would be about 20000 years on my computer, just to iterate... :\